# Is there a way to determine which degrees of freedom are lost in a robot at a singularity position by looking at the jacobian?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a 6DoF robot with all revolute joints the Jacobian is given by:
$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{z_0} \times (\vec{o_6}-\vec{o_0}) & \ldots & \hat{z_5} \times (\vec{o_6}-\vec{o_5})\\
\hat{z_0} & \ldots & \hat{z_5}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $z_i$ is the unit z axis of joint $i+1$(using DH params), $o_i$ is the origin of the coordinate frame connected to joint $i+1$, and $o_6$ is the origin of the end effector.  The jacobian matrix is the relationship between the Cartesian velocity vector and the joint velocity vector:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{X}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\dot{z}\\
\dot{r_x}\\
\dot{r_y}\\
\dot{r_z}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\mathbf{J}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\theta_1}\\
\dot{\theta_2}\\
\dot{\theta_3}\\
\dot{\theta_4}\\
\dot{\theta_5}\\
\dot{\theta_6}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\mathbf{J}\dot{\mathbf{\Theta}}
$$

Here is a singularity position of a Staubli TX90XL 6DoF robot:

[image: robot with joint 4 and joint 6 aligned pointed down]

$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50     &    -425     &    -750      &      0     &    -100      &      0\\
       612.92     &       0     &       0      &      0     &       0      &      0\\
            0     & -562.92     &       0      &      0     &       0      &      0\\
            0     &       0     &       0      &      0     &       0      &      0\\
            0     &       1     &       1      &      0     &       1      &      0\\
            1     &       0     &       0      &     -1     &       0      &     -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can easily see that the 4th row corresponding to $\dot{r_x}$ is all zeros, which is exactly the lost degree of freedom in this position.

However, other cases are not so straightforward.

[image: robot with joint 4 and joint 6 aligned pointed at an angle]
$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50   &   -324.52  &    -649.52   &         0   &   -86.603   &         0\\
       987.92   &         0  &          0   &         0   &         0   &         0\\
            0   &   -937.92  &       -375   &         0   &       -50   &         0\\
            0   &         0  &          0   &       0.5   &         0   &       0.5\\
            0   &         1  &          1   &         0   &         1   &         0\\
            1   &         0  &          0   &    -0.866   &         0   &    -0.866
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here you can clearly see that joint 4 and joint 6 are aligned because the 4th and 6th columns are the same.  But it's not clear which Cartesian degree of freedom is lost (it should be a rotation about the end effector's x axis in red).

Even less straightforward are singularities at workspace limits.

[image: robot at workspace limit with no aligned joint axes]

$$
\mathbf{J} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
          -50     &     650   &       325  &          0    &        0     &       0\\
       1275.8     &       0   &         0  &         50    &        0     &       0\\
            0     & -1225.8   &   -662.92  &          0    &     -100     &       0\\
            0     &       0   &         0  &    0.86603    &        0     &       1\\
            0     &       1   &         1  &          0    &        1     &       0\\
            1     &       0   &         0  &        0.5    &        0     &       0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In this case, the robot is able to rotate $\dot{-r_y}$ but not $\dot{+r_y}$.  There are no rows full of zeros, or equal columns, or any clear linearly dependent columns/rows.

Is there a way to determine which degrees of freedom are lost by looking at the jacobian?

Comment: Looking at the rigidity matroid might be what you're looking for  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigidity_matroid

Comment: I believe you are looking for the left null space of the Jacobian.

Comment: To expand slightly on Will Sawin's answer -- you know that at a singularity, the Jacobian does not have the full rank - hence there will be at least one nontrivial zero left eigenvector of the Jacobian matrix. All such eigenvectors correspond to the (linearizations of the) degrees of freedom which are lost.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with either the rigidity matroid or the left null space.  How would I compute them, and more importantly are there MATLAB functions for them?

Comment: After a bit of research, it looks like the left null space is returning a six element unit vector which points "toward" the lost degrees of freedom, i.e. the lost DoFs are larger in the vector than the non-lost DoFs.

For example, the second singularity position shown above has a left nullspace of [0, 0, 0, -0.866, 0, -0.5] which shows correctly that it loses a rotation dof in the x-z plane (world coordinates, not tool coordinates).